# Codeigniter + NetBeans + XDebug : Debugger not working after redirect()

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, netbeans-7, xdebug

I am working on a project that uses `CodeIgniter`. I use `Netbeans` as my IDE and I have `Xdebug` installed. I am using `XAMPP` for local development.

**What Works:** Xdebug is working fine for `normal PHP code.`

**Problem:** However, I am facing problems debugging my `CodeIgniter` project. Debugger stops on a `redirect()`

**Problem Details:** Start debugging project in netbeans. Debugger starts and we see homepage. On homepage, there is a link that corresponds to a method in homepage controller. *Debugger reaches the method in controller* to which the link points to. In this method there is a `redirect`. ***At the point of redirect debugger STOPS.***

**Relevant Code Snippet(s):**

*URL That is clicked* (This is part of the header menu)

```
<a href="<?= base_url("somefunc/"); ?>">Click Me </a>
```

*routes.php* - Reroute for prettier url.

```
$route['somefunc'] = "foo/somefunc";
```

And in my *Foo Controller* (foo.php):

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller {
    public function somefunc()
    {
        redirect('/bar/otherfunc');  // DEBUGGER REACHES TILL HERE THEN STOPS WORKING
    }
}
```

As said above in the comment in `function somefunc()`, Xdebug stops working at the place where the redirect happens.

Additionally, the following information might be of some use:

**config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; // I have also tried PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING, REQUEST_URI & ORIG_PATH_INFO.
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; // Have tried FALSE too.
$config['index_page'] = ''; // Tried index.php too.
```

**xdebug** settings in `php.ini`

```
zend_extension ="path\to\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

**NOTE** - I have already tried playing around with different suggestions that I have seen here as well as through google but to no avail. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You probably need to start debugging again in whatever script it redirects to.  Generally, `redirect()` functions include an `exit;` statement.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your comment. Your suggestion definitely works but I was hoping for a more robust solution instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution. Perhaps this might help someone else who has been struggling with this. Apparantly to allow smooth debugging, you need to include the option:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

in your `php.ini`. These settings work for me now:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

The last line is the option I found on ([Xdebug Official Documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)). The relevant part of the documentation is mentioned below:

**xdebug.remote_autostart**

*Type*: boolean, *Default value*: 0

Normally you need to use a specific HTTP GET/POST variable to start remote debugging (see Remote Debugging). When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try to connect to a client, even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problems, then try your suggestion: xdebug.remote_autostart=1 and now it works.

Comment: You are a god amongst men, thank you for answering your own question

Comment: wooow, you saved the day

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, and fixed it by upgrading my version of xdebug.

There appears to have been a bug in the version I was using (xdebug 2.1.3), but it all works fine on xdebug 2.2.3.

Use this tool for custom installation instructions for your environment.
http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that netbeans doenst work with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and url like `http://127.0.0.1/site/test.php/v1/v2/parametertoputonphpathinfo/v3`, there is a bug of `Mon Sep 09, 2013 8:54 am` on netbeans board telling about it without response until now 2014:

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic56645.html

It make impossible debug frameworks using that sinatra way to routing requests.
Rewriting my simple Sinatra router to have a $_GET mode to debug and a better hook code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow gsd15s6d465, your answer looks good to me. Would you be so kind to use correct inline code formatting for the code fragment and path by using backticks (`\``) surrounding the phrase?